# Haskell program that gives pretty prime numbers

Tags: haskell

I've made a haskell program that computes pretty prime numbers. Pretty primes are primes that are very close to a power of 2. You give 2 numbers for example: 10 and 20 then it returns 17 because 17 is the closest to a power of 2. 17 - 16 = 1 so it is the closest.

I've made this:

EDIT: I've rewrote the primefunction like this and e verw function but still getting -1.

```
  -- Geeft priemgetallen terug tussen de 2 grenzen
-- English: Gives primenumbers between 2 numbers
priemgetallen :: Int->[Int]
priemgetallen b = take b (zeef [2..])
    where zeef (p:xs) = p : zeef [x | x<-xs, (mod x p) /= 0]

-- Geeft machten terug tussen de 2 grenzen
-- English: Gives powers of 2 between 2 numbers
machten :: Int->Int->[Int]
machten a b 
        | a <= 2 = 2:[2^x| x<-[2..b], (2^x) `mod` 2 == 0, 2^x < b, 2^x > a]
        | otherwise = [2^x| x<-[2..b], (2^x) `mod` 2 == 0, 2^x < b, 2^x > a]

-- English: the start of the function
prettyprime :: Int->Int->Int
prettyprime a b = vergelijk ( verw a (priemgetallen b)) (machten a b)

-- Filter the list
verw :: Int->[Int]->[Int]
verw _ [] = []
verw k (x:xs)
    | x > k = [x] ++ verw k xs
    | otherwise = verw k xs

-- Vergelijkt alle priemgetallen en geeft welke korste bij het ander ligt
-- English this function must see what primenumber is the closest to a power of 2 but I can't fix it
vergelijk :: [Int]->[Int]->Int
vergelijk [] _ = -1
vergelijk _ [] = -1
vergelijk (x:xs) (y:ys)
            | x - y < vergelijk (x:xs) ys = x
            | x - y > vergelijk (x:xs) ys = vergelijk xs (y:ys)
            | x - y == vergelijk (x:xs) ys = x




main = do
       print $ prettyprime 14 20
```

Can someone help me?

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you be more specific as to **what exactly** your problem is?

Comment: the vergelijk function doesn't work. It has a Non exhaustive pattern. I don't see the problem :(. That function just needs to compare the list of primenumbers and powers of 2 and see what primenumber is the closest to a power of 2. So between 10 en 20 it should give 17. If there is no prime close to a power of 2 then it gives -1.

Comment: You might want to check your `priemgetallen` function - `priemgetallen 10 20` returns `[11,13,15,17,19]` and 15 isn't prime. 15 and 17 are equally close to 16, so your function could reasonably also return 15...

Comment: Indeed, that's the problem :s. I need to rewrite this :) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The incomplete pattern is because you've omitted the case when `x - y == vergelijk (x:xs) ys`. The compiler is capable of warning you about this if you add `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` and convert your guards into a real `case`:

```
vergelijk (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare (x - y) (vergelijk (x:xs) ys) of
    LT -> x
    -- you will get a warning about having no case for EQ
    GT -> vergelijk xs (y:ys)
```

As a bonus, this version is much less likely to recompute the recursive call, especially on low optimization levels.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice the case that they would be equal. Now it gives me between 10 and 20 the number 11 because it doesn't loop over the whole list :s, haskell gives me headache :D